# Package: "xorgxrdp" install failed! [Webmin]

Tags: linux, xorg, linux-kernel, webmin

What should I do to **fix this** on **Webmin** (web-based system configuration tool for Linux)?

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package xorgxrdp.x8664 0:0.2.6-1.el7 will be updated
---> Package xorgxrdp.x8664 0:0.2.6-2.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.19.5 for package: xorgxrdp-0.2.6-2.el7.x8664
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: xorgxrdp-0.2.6-2.el7.x8664 (epel)
Requires: xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.19.5
Installed: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el74.2.x8664 (@updates)
xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.19.3-11.el74.2
Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7.x8664 (base)
xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.19.3-11.el7
Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el74.1.x8664 (updates)
xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.19.3-11.el7_4.1
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> xorgxrdp
>
> Requires: xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.19.5

Version **1.19.5** is in the `CentOS-CR.repo`

Please edit (line 28) `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-CR.repo` to `enabled=1`

---

> Is this the temporary fix

CR.repo : The Continuous Release ( CR )  repository contains rpms that are due in the next release for a specific CentOS Version ( eg. next release in CentOS-7 )

- CentOS 7.5 will soon be released (RHEL 7.5 released Apr26,
  Scientific SL7.5: tomorrow).
- EPEL (Extra Packages for EL) : The extras for RHEL 7.5 are available.
  CentOS : A transition phase, the EPEL dependency on "CR" packages is probably temporary.

Quote : 7.5 is already available if you enable the CR repo ... https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=65681 → 2018/05/03 11:03:59

---

> Then what is the code for updating it with PuTTy (SSH)

Remote text editing ( sed, awk, perl, tee ). The `sed` command is :

```
sudo sed -i 's/enabled=0/enabled=1/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-CR.repo
```

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but do you have a reference source for this answer?

Comment: Updating it to 1.19.5 fix the issue?? Then what is the code for updating it with PuTTy (SSH) connection as administrator?

Comment: @mcnsvr: I guess you ca find a way editing `CentOS-CR.repo` with "PuTTy".

Comment: so what should I write on this editing? and I have no permisson to do this I have no full admin control

Comment: mcnsvr : Your question was " .. updating it with PuTTy (SSH) connection **as administrator** ?" ... No permission? : You can wait a few? weeks, for the "CentOS 7.5" Packages" to appear in the Base.repo ...

Comment: @KnudLarsen : I can wait but I will try to figure it out any way. I just use this command -> sudo yum update xorg-x11-server-Xorg  then result was ->  package xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el74.2.x8664 already installed and latest version

Comment: OR should I apply this suggestions on the top? : You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: mcnsvr.  Remote editing → Please see my edited answer : `sed` command.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I WRITE THIS: sudo sed -i 's/enabled=0/enabled=1/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-CR.repo   but then nothing happened

Comment: mcnsvr : Are you sure the path is right ? And what means »»then nothing happened«« ? ... Please note that the sed command is editing silently. You can see if the editing was done : `sudo cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-CR.repo` .... Look for the line `enabled=1`.

Comment: @KnudLarsen dude IT WORKS! :))) check my answer to this post in this page and see my screenshot

Comment: @KnudLarsen I saw the results and it says:  gpgcheck=1 , enabled=1   :)

Comment: @KnudLarsen hey, this solution is working with every issue like this?

Comment: There never were any issues, but there were solutions. And there is usually a solution for every task. And thousands of commands you can use to fix every day admin jobs. »working with every issue like this?« : Please be specific. ....

Comment: Yeah sure there are thousands of commands that I can use to fix as admin. I'll be specific: Except kernel update, can this "command" be considered a solution for every module that is not updated?

Comment: And by the way, how can I find or know thousands of commands that can be solution for any issues? Because I'm a junior for now you know.

Comment: The mentioned sed command replaces all XXX words in a file with XYY. Not really a universal thing, but useful if remote editing, and when editing data lists with "100" identical words. How to find commands generally : Search the Internet. I do. Just write the complete sentence with your demand / wish / problem in e.g. Google. Links:  **Rute**  https://rlworkman.net/howtos/rute/rute.html ....  LPIC https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/linux-system-administration-fundamentals

Comment: Yeah I do too but can't find. But I'll always keep searching. Thank you! Where can we stay in touch? just in case...